# JUnit: Is it possible to output multi-line messages in any of the assert functions?

Tags: java, junit, message, assert

I tried to get a multi-line message when there's an assert. e.g. I have the following code:

---

errLog = "ERROR! Account Name not found in result \n Expected Result: " + acctName + "\n" + "Actual Result: " + output + "\n";

assertTrue(errLog, output.contains(accountType));

---

*Where output is retrieved from the application during runtime and acctName is some data got passed in.*

The result I got is: 
ERROR! Account Name not found in result   Expected Result: Name123 Actual Result: My name is Name456  type:junit.framework.AssertionFailedError

The result I expected is: 
ERROR! Account Name not found in result 
Expected Result: Name123
Actual Result: My name is Name456 
type:junit.framework.AssertionFailedError

I've looked up everywhere online but it seemed like every example I read is only for output single line message. So, is it not possible to do multi-line messages using the existing assert functions? I know I can probably rewrite the assert function to accomodate what I need but as a newbie in JUnit, I guess it doesn't hurt to ask around first. **Thanks in advance**

Comment: I used Eclipse to test and the code produced the message in multi-line. How do you run your JUnit tests?

Comment: Why are you so concerned about the formatting of your error messages?  Ideally you should never see them.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this might come down to your IDE - I just ran the following in IntelliJ IDEA 12:

```
@Test
public void testABC() {
   assertTrue("This\nis\na\ntest", false);
}
```

and got back:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: This
is
a
test
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
```

The simplest (and more readble) way would be to write a function which extracts the account type from output, and use that in an assert:

```
assertEquals(acctName, extractAccountNameFromOutput(output));
```

which would give you a standard JUnit output if the test fails. When a test fails, you want the output to be immediately understandable, so it's probably better not to change the default output style provided by JUnit.

Comment: I guess there's a difference the way the log is being generated in my env. I don't see that level of details either. But it's good to know that should work and I did nothing wrong. Thanks a million!